# Styling react-native-elements CheckBox Icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using CheckBox from the react-native-elements. In the Documentation, there are not any IconProps. there is IconRight style which I used but it only aligning the Icon from the right of the title but I want to align the Icon at the end of the View.
here is the code -

```
        <CheckBox
                title={item}
                key={index}
                value={item}
                ref={item}
                checked={checked}
                iconRight
                iconType="material"
                checkedIcon="clear"
                uncheckedIcon="add"
                checkedColor="red"
                onPress={() => {
                    this.controlcheck(item, checked);
                }}
            />
```

[image: please see the image]

I want to align the `+` icon at the right of the end.

Comment: use grid row col module, or use flex layout flex direction flex-end

Comment: thanks for the response but I'm talking about Icon not full CheckBox layout

Comment: have you tried using checkedIcon and uncheckedicon to provide an icon component that has flex-end?

Comment: Please provide code along with View component wrapping the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
<CheckBox
            title={<Text style={{flex:1}}>Hello World</Text>}
            
        />
```